# How APEX stores files uploaded by users?

Tags: oracle-apex

I will be working on a web application on APEX soon. I noticed that APEX does not store files locally which were uploaded by users. So I wanted to know how does it work? And what can we say about privacy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APEX is a PL/SQL engine that lives on the Oracle database. It generates HTML pages, and sends them to the browser. Developers have a 'low code' web-based GUI to build these pages.

It's thin client, these files you've uploaded have nowehere 'local' to go. They are uploaded as binary content, inserted as rows in a table within the database, which has particularly secure design capabilities.

However, it's up to your implementation to ensure these files are only shown to the correct users.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean uploading a file for processing later, not static files like images and CSS files.

Reading the docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/htmdb/understanding-administrator-security-best-practices.html#GUID-84459D23-B43F-46DD-B6BD-9B83B79CF46A) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/htmdb/understanding-blob-support-in-forms.html#GUID-CD06A440-6864-401F-8709-DC69DEBE45EB) is a good place to start.